# NUnit cannot recognise a TestCase when it contains an Nullable Array

Tags: c#, arrays, nunit, nullable, testcase

I have test like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(new RequestStatus?[] {RequestStatus.Created, null, RequestStatus.Complete, null})]
public void MyClass_MyMethod( RequestStatus?[] testCaseRequest )
{
  ...
}
```

Nuint doesn't recognise Nullable Array as TestCase param. I got this:

An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Comment: You might have to look at using `TestCaseSource`, as mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479817/how-do-i-put-new-listint-1-in-an-nunit-testcase   and here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687091/passing-a-string-to-attribute-argument-by-calling-method

Comment: I found answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479817/how-do-i-put-new-listint-1-in-an-nunit-testcase

Comment: Nice one :) Glad you've solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `params` as a method argument:

```
[TestCase(RequestStatus.Created, null, RequestStatus.Complete, null)]
public void MyClass_MyMethod(params RequestStatus?[] requestStatus)
{
    // ...
}
```